# Query avançada em Ruby On Rails (ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Preciso fazer uma *query* para um relatório mais ou menos assim:

```
Produto.include(:clientes).where('count(produto.id) < cliente.quantidade')
```

Em *sql* seria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT 
    C.NOME, C.QUANTIDADE, COUNT(P.ID)
FROM PRODUTOS AS P 
LEFT JOIN CLIENTES AS C ON P.CLIENTE_ID = C.ID 
WHERE COUNT(P.ID) < C.QUANTIDADE
```

Como fazer isso utilizando o **Active Record**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível fazer *where* com count desta maneira, você precisa utilizar o *having*. Isso resolveu o problema.

```
Produto.joins(:cliente)
       .group(:nome, :quantidade)
       .having('count(produtos.id) < clientes.quantidade')
       .count(:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho muita experiência com `Active Record`, mas vê se te da uma luz:

```
Produto.find(:all,
            joins:  "INNER JOIN `clientes` ON clientes.id = produtos.cliente_id" ,
            select: "clientes.nome, clientes.quantidade, count(produtos.id)", 
            group:  "clientes.nome, clientes.quantidade")
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer isso funcionar no rails 4. Acho que desta maneira somente nas versões anteriores. Obrigado.